# how to add reference of one spring boot application to another spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot

1. I want to make a spring boot product base application.
2. In that I want to make  a different spring application depends on each other by adding reference of one application to another application.
3. And make seperate jars of each and put it into tomcat

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ It looks as though you are asking for someone to provide you with code _ Unfortunately this is NOT what Stack Overflow is for _ Please take a moment to visit the Help Center and specifically the section on 'Asking' _ This will give you more understanding of what this site is used for >>> 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please go through the code of conduct https://stackoverflow.com/conduct , Meanwhile you can add write about waht you ahve done till so far to solve achieve your target.

Comment: Now I have solved this issue by adding another module reference in the classpath using build-Path->Configure build path in STS

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to start with simple hello-world application and later you can scale your application up.

Simple way is go to 'start.spring.io', add dependencies like spring boot starter web.
You can download the project after adding dependencies. Now, just import the project in your eclipse as 'import existing maven project'.
Spring boot has inbuilt tomcat, simply right click on the import project and select 
run as --> java application
Your application will start on port 8080.

Now, you can create one more similar application and can run the application on port 8081 by adding a property server.port=8081 in your 2nd application.

You can call the api of 1st application from 2nd application.

If you are planning to create microservices, then please read about **spring cloud**.